# Best way to prepare hierarchical data for easy querying in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I'm starting to use MongoDB for a new project and wanted to insert customer data into it using this scheme:

```
{
    admin: {mail: "", realName: {first: "", last: ""}, address: {street: "", city: "", state: ""}, payment: {type: "", blz: "", account: ""}},
    users: [
        {mail: "", password: "", realName: {first: "", last: ""}},
        ...
    ],
    categories: [
        {name: "", assignedUsers: [{ID: "", readOnly: true}, ...], entries: [
            {name: "", tags: "", site: "", user: "", pass: "", notes: ""}
        ],
        ...
    ]
}
```

However, I've found out that it isn't easily possible to, for example, get one of the users in the "users" array by it's mail address or to get all categories that one user is assigned to by his ID.

So it seems like I'd have to split my hierarchical data into multiple collections, but I'm not sure what the best way to do that is. How would you recommend me to split this data?

Comment: what you use to get the data from Mongo? where "it isn't easily possible" - in terminal, in Node.js?

Comment: I'm currently accessing MongoDB using the terminal (mongo)

Comment: ..., but I'm planning on using MongoJS in Node.js to access the data later. If there is an easy way to query the data without modifying its structure, that would also be great :)

Comment: write you terminal query with what you have a problem

Comment: for example, if I want to write a login method, I would have to `find()` all `users` whose mail address matches a certain string. I tried it using `db.customers.findOne({"users.mail": "mail@address.org"})` and this method returns the full document where one of the users has got a matching mail address. Now, I'd like to get only the user instead of the whole document. Running `db.customers.findOne({"users.mail": "mail@address.org"}).users` returns the whole users array. However, I couldn't find a solution to run a query against this array.

Comment: find works on document level. So will return always whole docs for you. What you can try is to use aggregation framework and unwind users and match for the credentials you like to match for. With this you will get one along with all the other data. Or process the whole doc in your application. (Or think about to redesign your document structure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are locking for [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) and [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#projection). Its optional operator that specifies the fields to return using projection operators and it's boolean **1 - show** & **0 - hide**

  `db.customers.findOne({"users.mail": "mail@address.org"}, {users: 1})`
- That's not secure to use `findOne({"users.mail": "mail"})` for authentication, there is special Node.js module [PassportJS](http://passportjs.org/).

Comment: When I'm using `db.customers.findOne({"users.mail": "mail@address.org"}, {users: 1})`, I'm getting back the users array but I still don't know which of the entries inside of the array actually match the mail address. I don't think it is possible to run a query against this returned array. `db.customers.findOne({"users.mail": "admin@leolabs.org"}, {users: 1}).users.findOne({"mail": "mail@address.org"})` for example doesn't work.